# What is the architectural decision for using /tmp directory in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

What is the concept of using **/tmp** folder in hadoop or what is the architectural decision for using **/tmp** folder. Why not data is directly copied directly to FSImage or Editlog?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the main purpose of HDFS /tmp directory is to store temporary files during map reduce execution.

While running the map reduce jobs, it creates many intermediate files which are temporary and are cleared out once execution is completed.

While **fsimage** contains entire file system namespace, including the mapping of blocks to files and file system properties.
And **editlog** represent all the namesystem modifications made since the creation of the fsimage.

**/tmp** files will be cleaned up after execution completion.

All serve different purpose.

Answer (score 1):

FSImage and the Editlog are in RAM, if I read about those correctly ([link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26943161/namespace-image-and-edit-log), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23181824/where-does-name-node-store-fsimage-and-edit-log)).

The top aspects of the `/tmp` folder could be that it...

- does not get cleared on cluster restart
- is **not** considered a Trash directory
- doesn't enforce permission rights such as those directories in the home directory and therefore can be shared between processes
- remains as part of HDFS as a distributed file space

Other than that, the reason it is used is likely to be similar to the use-case of any Unix environment.